# iOS: confused about using the AppDelegate properly

Tags: iphone, ios

Still really new to iOS dev (have a background in asp.net / web), and I don't think I've quite gotten my head around how everything relates to everything else.  For example, I'm building an app at the moment which starts with a NavigationController.  I'm passing ViewControllers in and out of that quite happily and everything is working but now I need to add a rightbutton to the navigation controller.  I have done this from within one of the ViewControllers like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
UIBarButtonItem *change = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"CHANGE" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(navAlert)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = change;

[change release];

[super viewDidLoad];
}

 - (void)navAlert
{

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"nav pressed" message:@"You pressed the Change button" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Yep" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];
[alert release];
}
```

but I don't want to have to do that in each controller - should something like this go into the AppDelegate and be called from there?

Also, suppose I didn't want to start with a NavigationController - could I use code in the AppDelegate to release ViewControllers and load new ones directly into the Window, by clicking a button which is set up in a ViewController?

Sorry if this is a bit of a stupid question, but I don't think I've quite grasped how the different layers relate, what code is available to which controller, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **not** put interface related code inside the appdelegate. That's what the ViewControllers are there for. If there's functionality which is common to *all* of your viewcontrollers, I'd suggest subclassing UIViewController (and then deriving all other instances from this subclass) or writing a category on it.

The appdelegate on the other hand is a good place to trigger basic events tied to the lifespan of the app, like setting up core data contexts or saving the application state when it is about to enter the background.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Just need to carry on experimenting a bit and it will slot into place eventually.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do in `viewDidLoad` is have a proper "back" button in your `UINavigationController`, you don't need to do it that way. Simply define the `title` property of your controller to what you like. The controller's `init` method will do for that (no need in this case for `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.title = @"CHANGE";
```

or you can set it in the appDelegate:

```
controller.title = @"CHANGE";
```

As to your other question, best thing is start from scratch with a view based or window based project template.

Otherwise, you are quite right: you can release predefined controllers you don't need from the appDelegate and create your own. Additionally, you should take care of  removing all those controllers' views from their parent:

```
 [controller.view removeFromSuperview];
```

(for each controller you remove and for which there was a `[self.window addSubview]` in you delegate, possibly just the `UiNavigationController`).

Anyway, I don't know if I can suggest this path, because you would also need to fix all the dependencies related to the xib files, and would give you some headaches.

Comment: It was actually to have a second button which take you to kind of a settings screen for the app, which I'm doing by popping the navigation controller back to index 0, the Alert bit is just some code I put in while testing